# Tell a chart that the first two rows should be the legend area?

Tags: vba, excel

When I change a charts source data with the following command:

```
wksGraph.ChartObjects("Split").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=wksGraph.Range("$AA$2:$AE$" & FirstEmptyRow(wksGraphSplit.Range("$AA$3")) - 1)
```

**The first row** becomes the legend as you can see in this image. But can I instead tell Excel to treat **the first two rows** as legend?

[image: attached image]

Comment: Can you include a picture of your current chart? And also a description of the desired output or how that would differ from current state? I'm having trouble understanding how you'd want to use two rows for the legend entries (also, not sure this is possible, since I think the legend entries are linked to the series data...)

Comment: I want the legend to become "A Tar", "A Not", "B Tar" and "B Not", then I want the series data points to be at the rows A, B, C, D ...

Comment: seems like the easy solution is to simply update the values in row 2...

Comment: You're right. That was dubm of me and smart of you :) I'll close this question.

Comment: No worries!! Sometimes when you're neck-deep in code, you just need a second opinion to point out the obvious. I've been there before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this not suffice? The solution would be to simply specify the correct labels by concatenating the values as desired.

```
Range("AB2").Value = Range("AB1").Value & " " & Range("AB2").Value
Range("AC2").Value = Range("AC1").Value & " " & Range("AB2").Value
Range("AD2").Value = Range("AD1").Value & " " & Range("AD2").Value
Range("AE2").Value = Range("AE1").Value & " " & Range("AD2").Value

wksGraph.ChartObjects("Split").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=wksGraph.Range("$AA$2:$AE$" & FirstEmptyRow(wksGraphSplit.Range("$AA$3")) - 1
```

I checked to see if you could hijack the legend entries, but it appears not.

From the [MS documentation on the `LegendEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840546.aspx), the text cannot be changed and is linked to the source:

> The text of a legend entry cannot be changed. LegendEntry objects support font formatting, and they can be deleted. No pattern
>   formatting is supported for legend entries. The position and size of
>   entries is fixed.